# Summarize list by property

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of objects like this:

```
List<ClassName> list = new List<ClassName>();
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Name = 1,
    Amount = 5
});
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Name = 2,
    Amount = 10
});
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Name = 1,
    Amount = 20
});
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Name = 3,
    Amount = 10
});
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Name = 3,
    Amount = 15
});
```

Now I would like to summarize this list by the property `Name`. The result should contain one entry for every `Name` and the sum of `Amount` of the entries with the same `Name`.
So this would be the expected result:

```
List<ClassName> list = new List<ClassName>();
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Name = 1,
    Amount = 25
});
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Name = 2,
    Amount = 10
});
list.Add(new ClassName()
{
    Name = 3,
    Amount = 25
});
```

How can I archive this?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, are you expected to work from a specific set of C# features? (that you've been introduced to already in your course)

Comment: No, it's no homework ;-) I just came along this problem in a private project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var lst = list.GroupBy(g = > g.Name).Select(t = > new
 ClassName()
 {
     Amount = t.Sum(s=>s.Amount), Name = t.Key
 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it via LINQ:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new ClassName { Name = x.Key, Amount = x.Sum(i => i.Amount) })
    .ToList();
```

Read more about LINQ here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new MyClass() {Name=x.Key, Amount= x.Sum(y => y.Amount));
```

OR

```
List<MyClass> result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new MyClass() {Name=x.Key, Amount= x.Sum(y => y.Amount)).ToList();
```